# Notation in statistics

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, notation

I'm reading an old document and I came across a notation I'm unsure of,

[image]

E.g. the first equation states a uniform distribution given by $\frac{1}{2\pi}$. However, I don't understand the $\mathrm{d}\phi$ on both sides of the equation (I assume It's not a differential and if it is then what for?). The same goes for the second equation. Also, I assume that $p(\phi)$ is the notation for "the probability of a certain $\phi$, but in the second distribution, it's noted $N$? Would anyone give me an explanation of how it should be interpreted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a differential.

If you formally integrate the equation over any interval on both sides you'll see that it's defining a uniform distribution

$$ \int_a^b P(\phi) d \phi = \int_a^b \frac{d \phi}{2 \pi} = \frac{b - a}{2 \pi} $$

as long as $a$ and $b$ are in the support of the distribution.

I'm not sure about the second equation, interpreting that seems to need some domain knowledge.  But I would expect the use of the differentials to be the same.